# Web API authentication with Kerberos

Tags: api, kerberos, web, sspi

We are implementing a web application that uses Kerberos for authentication. In the browser there is no concerns, so it works perfect. Now we need to supply a subset of web application services via web API.
Getting Kerberos ticket once with `InitializeSecurityContext()` of Windows SSPI, and sending it in `Authorization` header of one request is working but is there a good way to obtain ticket once and use it for multiple requests (as long as ticket does not expires)? For now it is OK for a period under time skew limit (default: 5 min.).